# EF Core 7, how to check if navigation property is loaded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I have an EF Core 7 POCO class. Example:

```
public class A
{
    // ... omitted unrelated properties

    public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer MyCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

The `MyCustomer` property is lazy loaded occasionally. If it is loaded, I will display the customer's detail. If not, will just ignore.

My question is, how can I check if the value is loaded without getting a `LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning`? The `DbContext` is long gone by the time I receive this object.

Comment: Isn't it just a `!= null` check? Please [edit] your question to include the source code, where you try to access the navigation property and where you get the exception. Also include the full exception message to your question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you please explain the use case for this? This seems slightly smelly, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[NavigationEntry.IsLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry.isloaded#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-changetracking-navigationentry-isloaded) is what you ideally want here, but it only works as long as you still have a DbContext. Otherwise, you'll have to just [disable the warning entirely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3#suppress-logging-an-event).

If you don't end up in situations where you have to do these weird checks to begin with, then you won't have any problems. I'd first reconsider whether the design that led you to this problem is good in the first place. You should not be branching your logic based on whether an entity was loaded or not. Use something more explicit: separate methods, boolean arguments, separate DTOs with `IFooWithBar`-like interfaces for various combinations of loaded data.

You could also do explicit loading to get rid of the warnings, but having to do these sorts of null checks in the first place would still mean that you're leaking your DB logic onto your entities, which is non-ideal if you care about isolating your domain from other concerns.

Or more obviously, just don't dispose of the DbContext if you actually still need it.

Comment: Thanks, I made a query to the Database (EF) layer, and based on my UserID, the db will decide whether to return the client's detail. They returned the EF POCO object, but I have no way to check if the details had been loaded.